# Javascript: Cannot set property of undefined; using function as class

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I used function() as class and I create some propeties using `this.` scope:

```
function field(newMaxX, newMaxY) {
    this.maxX = newMaxX;
    this.maxY = newMaxY;
}
```

But this caused this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'maxX' of undefined

I have already write [project](http://www.gvp.cz/~vecernik/snake/) with same using of function without error.

```
function snake(nX, nY, nScore, nDirection, maxX, maxY, cellSize) {
    this.cells = [];
    this.score = nScore;
    ...
}
```

Also JQuery points out at this problem:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot set property 'maxX' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'maxX' of undefined

I don't know how to fix that. Please help.

Comment: This code is completely fine. You can simply paste it inside your console and see that it works fine. Can you please share the code where you call it? The error should be somewhere else

Comment: are in instantiating your `snake` function with the `new` keyword somewhere or applying the context via `.call`, `.apply`, or `.bind` methods? I think you need to edit and provide more information. (as an aside, if you're declaring a class, I'm talking about `snake`, it's best practice to captialize the name, e.g. `function Snake(){}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I find the problem. I just forget to use `new` keyword:

```
gameArea = field(parseInt(MAX_X / CELL_SIZE), parseInt(MAX_Y / CELL_SIZE));
```

That doesn't work but this does:

```
gameArea = new field(parseInt(MAX_X / CELL_SIZE), parseInt(MAX_Y / CELL_SIZE));
```

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Here's a trick to help you [avoid forgetting to call `new`](http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html)

Comment: @theRadek - One thing you should definitely do, whether you use the trick Juan mentioned or not, is to follow the standard JavaScript convention and begin constructor names with a capital letter and all other functions with a lowercase letter. When you do this consistently, the capital letter will become a reminder to use `new`. So this function should be named `Field()` instead of `field()`. Then when you see a bare call to `Field()` without `new`, it will just _look_ wrong, and conversely, if you see `new field()`, that will also look wrong.

Comment: That will also make it easier for people to read your code, since most JavaScript programmers will expect to find constructors named with a capital letter.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Also note that if the OP uses capital letters at the beginning of constructors, they can use linting (http://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap) to help you find places where constructors are called without `new`